# OxyPlot WPF get selected data point

Tags: wpf, mouseevent, oxyplot

I have an Oxyplot chart displaying a lineseries, shown as follows

```
                    <oxy:Plot x:Name="MyChart"
                              Title="Real"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              Grid.Column="0">
                        <oxy:Plot.Series>
                            <oxy:LineSeries Title="MySeries"/>
                        </oxy:Plot.Series>
                        <oxy:Plot.Axes>
                            <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" TicklineColor="White" Title= "MySeries"/>
                            <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" TicklineColor="White" />    
                        </oxy:Plot.Axes>
                    </oxy:Plot>
```

When the user left clicks on the line, the tracker is displayed, showing the selected data point. I would like to have a handler in my code to get the selected data point but am not sure the correct way to do this.

I have tried adding a handler as follows

```
    this.MyChart.ActualModel.MouseDown += OxyMouseDown;

    private void OxyMouseDown(object sender, OxyMouseDownEventArgs e)
    {
        LineSeries lineSeries = sender as LineSeries;
        if (lineSeries != null)
        {
            double x = lineSeries.InverseTransform(e.Position).X;
        }
    }
```

However, although the handler gets called, the sender is never of type LineSeries and therefore I can never transform the point.

Can someone help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `Plot` element with a `PlotView` element and create a `PlotModel` to which you add your series and axes:

```
PlotModel plotModel = new PlotModel() { Title = "Real" };
LineSeries lineSeries = new LineSeries() { Title = "MySeries" };
plotModel.Series.Add(lineSeries);
//...and add the axes
MyChart.Model = plotModel;
```

**XAML:**

```
<oxy:PlotModel x:Name="MyChart" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Then you should be able to handle the event of the `LineSeries`:

```
lineSeries.MouseDown += OxyMouseDown;
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't compile for me as lineSeries.MouseDown wants a handler of type (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e).

Comment: Also, when I change the handler to use MouseButtonEventArgs, the handler never gets called when I click on the chart.

Comment: @user5265160: Replace the `Plot` element with a `PlotView` element and create a `PlotModel`. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. How do I bind to plotmodel series? This has no  ItemsSource.

Comment: @user5265160: You bind the `Model` property to a `PlotModel` and add the series to the `Series` property of the `PlotModel` as I showed you.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestions. I am using MVVM with the reactive UI framework. This may be more complicated than I was hoping for. I will try your solution another time, however, for my simple cartesian graph it is much quicker for me to use LiveCharts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this solution is know deprecated.
All events except for PlotView where marked as such.

The answer is that the binding of new events should be declared in a PlotController. an exemple is provided [here](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/Examples/ExampleLibrary/Examples/PlotControllerExamples.cs).

to go further, the event can be handled more specifically by this way:

```
_sectionPlotCtrl.BindMouseDown(OxyMouseButton.Left, new DelegateViewCommand<OxyMouseDownEventArgs>(myPlot_HandleMouseDown));

...

private void myPlot_HandleMouseDown(IView view, IController controller, OxyMouseDownEventArgs e)
 {
      //handle mouse down stuff
 }
```

the oxyMouseDownEventArgs has a hitTestResult, that would return the nearest point from the serie.